# Youtube videos acting weird in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, modal-dialog

I use bootstrap's modal, and in it embed a youtube iframe. The youtube works but acting weird: when opening the modal, it appears for a second, but then disappears. In some cases it appears again when hovering with the mouse above it, In same cases it doesn't, and it appears only when closing the modal and re-opening it. 
Any suggestions for that kind of behaviour?

Code of the modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id='Hanale_modal' class='modal fade autoModal' role='dialog'>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >

  <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content autoModal" style='margin:auto;'>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class='modal_upper_part'>
          <p>
            <iframe class='modal_youtube hide_on_collapsed' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ksm4gS48Ov0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen ></iframe >
          </p>
        </div>  
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you replicate this issue in fiddle?

Comment: It uses a lot of bootstraps' css and jquery so I don't see how I can fit all of it in a fiddle.

Comment: You can just add link to bootstrap in external resources tab of fiddle..

Comment: I'm trying but looks like modal is can't be opened properly in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div class='modal_upper_part'> 
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. sorry. It makes the video disappear completely.